# CMake include_directories for custom target type

Tags: cmake

I have a custom target with .cpp and .h source files. As normal, those files include other header files. I'd like to add a directory for header files to be looked from.

This might sounds easy so far, but here's the twist. I'm using a custom target and custom commands to compile and link the program. The actual compiler needs another type of project file, which is not compatible with CMake.

If I try to add include directories to my current target, I'm greeted with the following error:

```
target_include_directories called with non-compliant target type.
```

The reason I think that this might be possible is that you *can* add header file lookup paths in the Visual Studio project I'm creating from CMake. I would not like to do this, because it's not persistent and everyone on my team would have to do it too. And what's worse, I would have to *explain* it to them ... (shudders)

---

EDIT:

To answer comments, I'm generating Visual Studio 2017 project files.
My custom target command is just:

```
add_custom_target(APP
DEPENDS ${APP_DEPENDENCIES}
SOURCES ${APP_DEPENDENCIES}
)
```

and my custom command is:

```
add_custom_command(
OUTPUT "${LIB_COMPILE_DIR}/libAPP.a"
DEPENDS ${LIB_COMPILE_SRCS}
COMMAND gbuild -top ${LIB_COMPILE_DIR}/App.gpj
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIB_COMPILE_DIR}
)
```

I'm aware that CMake has a generator for GHS MULTI but it is quite experimental and doesn't work in my case.

Comment: have you tried vanilla [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd guess it only adds the include directories to valid targets. And my target isn't one of them sadly.

Comment: can you share your custom target and custom commands? what are you using to build this? can you use VERBOSE=1 to show what is being passed the compilers?

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: Well, kinda and kinda no. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly. I think it's possible to have the include paths added into the generated project file via script. I didn't try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is interested in getting this to work, here is a simple recipe which is similar to the one I proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73900773/13613140).

1. Define a variable to store the required include paths (example):

```
list(APPEND MY_INCLUDE_PATHS "${my_helpers_include}")
list(APPEND MY_INCLUDE_PATHS "${my_project_include}")
# ...
```

2. Create a simple `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.user` template xml-file for C/C++ in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`:

```
    file(
        WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.user"
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<Project ToolsVersion=\"Current\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003\">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludePath>$(IncludePath);@MY_INCLUDE_PATHS@</IncludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>"
    )
```

3. And finally configure the template for whatever target you need:

```
configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.user"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${my_target}.vcxproj.user"
    @ONLY
)
```

Template name, template directory, all the variables starting with `my_` and even the steps can be modified in several ways. At the end it only matters that the xml-file `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${my_target}.vcxproj.user` exists for your custom target with the xml-content from above.

Comment: I kinda remember doing something similar back when I worked on this

Comment: This works well, but you need to escape those double quotes in order to get correct XML generated. Please @P. B. update the answer. Thx

Comment: Thanks for spotting this @m1lhaus. I've updated the answer but I cannot test it directly in CMake atm. - hope to have catched all the missing escapes.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, in that I needed to supply the include directories to a custom target. My solution is not brilliant, but it seems to address the problem at hand. I obtained the paths in the include directories, and formatted them into the required inputs for my compiler (in this case ODB[1]).

```
    get_directory_property(dirs INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    set(global_includes "")
    foreach(dir IN LISTS dirs)
        set(global_includes ${global_includes} -I ${dir})
    endforeach()
```

I then used `${global_includes}` in the command of the custom target. I wanted to move to the new world of `target_include_directories`, but haven't managed to make it work in this scenario.

[1] https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/download.xhtml

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear question, I should have said that I wanted to give the paths to visual studio so that Intellisense would work. The compilation step is not the problem, just that visual studio highlight almost every line with red because it cannot find the header files. I did my own research and found that it's not possible with CMake, unless I make a script that inserts the include paths into the generated visual studio project file after it has been generated by CMake. It's not as simple a problem as it might first seem.