# Debugging CMake Visual Studio project with PATH environment set by VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, compilation

I've created a CMake project using visual studio 2019. It has one executable target, which links to some shared libraries (DLL). I cannot directly set the system environment variable PATH because the DLL path is determined by find_package. Therefore, set VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT target property is my choice to debug that executable target.

However, the VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT property is not working when I directly open the CMake project and debug that target. I've checked the .vsproj it has the correct LocalDebuggerEnvironment tag generated.

But if I run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ../`  and open the generated visual studio solution and then debug the subproject from there, everything turns out to be ok.

I think maybe the visual studio doesn't support LocalDebuggerEnvironment when opening project as a CMake project. Or perhaps I didn't debug it the right way. Is there anything else I can do to change the visual studio debug runtime PATH environment using CMake?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You tagged C++, so I guess your dealing with a C++ target? I'm actually struggling with the same problem and tried to use both VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT and VS_USER_PROPS (with a user.props file) per target and globally via properties but not a single Environment was set in Visual Studio 2019. I tried all solutions that I found on SO. May I ask whether you have gotten any further?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @P.B. , I've given up on trying to change the environment variables.  I enabled [CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VS_INCLUDE_INSTALL_TO_DEFAULT_BUILD.html) and used [install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-runtime-dependencies) to install all runtime dependencies to the directory containing my output binary. I don't think it's the best way, but that's all I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @b39b332d. I also completely forgot about my own comment here. The way you ended up was sadly not feasible for my project as it took ages for VS 2019 to collect/copy all the dependent libraries with each debugging attempt. Below is a possible workaround using template files which I'm happy with today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to share what I finally ended up with after some painful hours of digging through the web.

1. First, a variable to store the required debugging paths is needed (example):

```
list(APPEND VS_DEBUGGING_PATH "%PATH%")
list(APPEND VS_DEBUGGING_PATH "${PostgreSQL_ROOT}/bin")
```

2. The next step is to create a `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.user` template file for C/C++ and in my case also a `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vfproj.user` template for FORTRAN (just for the record):

```
    file(
        WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.user"
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<Project ToolsVersion=\"15.0\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003\">
    <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'\$(Configuration)'=='Release'\">
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'\$(Configuration)'=='MinSizeRel'\">
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'\$(Configuration)'=='RelWithDebInfo'\">
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'\$(Configuration)'=='Debug'\">
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>"
    )
    file(
        WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vfproj.user"
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<VisualStudioUserFile>
    <Configurations>
        <Configuration Name=\"Release|x64\" Environment=\"PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@\"/>
        <Configuration Name=\"MinSizeRel|x64\" Environment=\"PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@\"/>
        <Configuration Name=\"RelWithDebInfo|x64\" Environment=\"PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@\"/>
        <Configuration Name=\"Debug|x64\" Environment=\"PATH=@VS_DEBUGGING_PATH@\"/>
    </Configurations>
</VisualStudioUserFile>"
    )
```

As you might see, both template files are just dumped into the root of `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` in this case. The base name `${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}` is also arbitrary.

3. Those templates can then finally be "configured" (copied) into each target folder of your setup. Either for C/C++

```
configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vcxproj.user"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${target_name}.vcxproj.user"
    @ONLY
)
```

or FORTRAN

```
configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.vfproj.user"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${target_name}.vfproj.$ENV{USERNAME}.user"
    @ONLY
)
```

or even both if necessary. The variable `${target_name}` needs to replaced with your target name of course. :-)

This should suffice. It is however important to close VS 2019 before (re-)configuring/(re-)generating with CMake. Otherwise VS 2019 might simply overwrite those files for each target.

I strongly hope this is helpful.
Please let me know if you need more details.

Here is the result for C/C++ targets [image: Debugging environment for C/C++] and here for FORTRAN targets [image: Debugging environment for FORTRAN]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a more elegant way than I expected. But I still hope that one day Microsoft Team will make VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT property work.

Comment: You are welcome! It is still a workaround though and I'm also very much looking forward to get the VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT property to work. It is still unclear whether this is a bug or missing feature. At least from the CMake docs it seems that it "should" work for VS 2010 and above. Maybe there is someone out there who knows why it doesn't...